# transactions within spring beans

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, transactions

my application conatians hibernate and spring frameworks, on tamcat server and mysql.

i annotated a function as transactional, and i saw that it not behaves as transacitonal method (e.g i can see the changes in the DB in query browser, before the function finish).

the method is executed from a bean, but in different thread, like this:

```
    executor.submit(new Runnable(){

        @Override
        public void run() {

            someSpringService.doDbStuff();
        }
    });
```

inside doDbStuff, i am calling to several method, and each method using the template, like this:

```
    return getHibernateTemplate().execute(new HibernateCallback(){
        public Object doInHibernate(Session session) throws HibernateException, SQLException {
            return session.createCriteria(MyClass.class).add(Restrictions.eq("id", id))
                    .uniqueResult();
        }
    });
```

sometimes, i also exeuctue within the HiberateCallback native sql query, using the session i get as an argument to doInHiberate.

my questions are -
1. is the transactional annotation ignored because i am using different thread?
2. how can i execute the function that is annotated with transactional annotation as a spring bean (and not as a regular function - maybe it will solve 1 )?
3. if i create several HibernateCallback's within a callstack containing transactional annotation - is it behave as a transactional method? do i have to use the same session, and pass it between the inner functions?

thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> i can see the changes in the DB in query browser, before the function finish

When you run your method not from within a thread does it behave differently? This might be MySQL/transaction isolation issue...

> 1. is the transactional annotation ignored because i am using different thread?

Not in this case. If you were creating a transaction in one thread and then spawning a new one, the latter would not "inherit" the transaction. In your case the transaction should start inside a new thread, behaving correctly.

Also try running this inside `doDbStuff()`:

```
TransactionSynchronizationManager.isActualTransactionActive()
```

to make sure.

> 1. how can i execute the function that is annotated with transactional annotation as a spring bean (and not as a regular function - maybe it will solve 1 )?

What do you mean? If you are calling `someSpringService` was injected by Spring and `doDbStuff()` is a public method annotated with `@Transactional` - it should just work. There are a few gotchas, however for instance - if you are inside a bean calling public transactional method from private non-transactional one might not work.

> 1. if i create several HibernateCallback's within a callstack containing transactional annotation - is it behave as a transactional method? do i have to use the same session, and pass it between the inner functions?

`HibernateCallback` is clever enough to reuse the same JDBC connection -> Hibernate session -> transaction.

Comment: i checked TransactionSynchronizationManager.isActualTransactionActive(), and as i thought - it returned false. i assume that the problem is that i execute the spring bean as a regular function, from a different thread (the callstack of the transactional annotated function doesn't contain spring classes...). do u know how to execute the funciton as regular bean?

Comment: BTW - if i use hibrtnateTemplate.beginSession().startTransaction() and commit it at the end of the function - still, the inner functions doesn't recognize the transaction.

Comment: How do you obtain `someSpringService`? Try executing `someSpringService.doDbStuff();` before `executor.submit()` (in the same thread). Does it work then? If so, it deserves a second question.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have

```
<tx:annotation-driven/>
```

in your applicationContext.xml.